# Pointing Visual Studio 2008 to the source code of a third-party DLL for debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, dll

I have a VS 2008 C++ project which uses a third-party library (Open Scene Graph).

When i start debugging the project, each time a function from this external library is called, the debugger just jumps over it, because (obviously) the debugger has no .cpp files where to look up the code. It only jumps into header files which are linked to my project because those files exist and their location is known. So, i can only see what's going on in those small inline functions, but not in the bigger functions whose implementation is in .cpp files which i don't have.

I need is to somehow step thru the source code of these third-party dlls/libs the same way I do with my own code.

I downloaded the the whole source code of that library and compiled it on my machine. Now i have the dlls and libs, and the .pdb files, and the .cpp files, too. But how exactly do I tell Visual Studio the locations of the .cpp files of the third-party library, so that it knows, that when i want to step into a function coming from a .dll or a .lib it opens the corresponding .cpp file (even though it's not in my project and is located is a completely different folder)?

Is this at all possible?

I tried copying the .libs, the .dlls (debug versions), .pdbs both to the locations which my Project uses and "Additional Library Directories" and to the project's folder but this must be not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Add the dir with the PDB files to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols.

Comment: Checked http://www.symbolsource.org/ and is says that i also need to specify the location of the source code. For Microsoft products special servers for .pdb and .cpp files are used, but the library with which I work (Open Scene Graph) is not a Microsoft one, of course, so it's not on their server!

Comment: Here is what I would have to do if the library were from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503. Open Scene Graph of course doesn't have anything like this.

Comment: The PDB files themselves point to the source code (and in fact the binaries point to the PDBs), so if you've built things yourself and haven't moved the source and/or PDBs afterwards then Visual Studio should find things automatically. If the PDBs aren't in their original location then the symbol paths (the setting I mentioned) should be set to point to them. I think VS will then prompt you for source files if it cannot find them. Saying that, I've found it is quite fiddly... My advice is to run Process Monitor and see what VS is looking for and where! That's what I do when it doesn't work.

Comment: Finally got it working. Yes, indeed, one just has to build the third party from code in debug mode and then just link the place where the dlls and pdb of the library are produced to the main project. Visual Studio opens the .cpp files belonging to the library. Thanks a lot for help!